# how to ip routing between windows server and remote linux box

Tags: linux, windows, networking, iptables, routing

I have the following network setup and having issues trying to connect. I would appreciate if you could give me some ideas about it.

My devices are

-*VPN server on amazon EC2 (windows server 2016)*
Has IP 10.0.1.1

-*Raspberry on a remote location (running raspbian)* Has:

- 2 physical connections.

  - wlan0 is where it gets internet access.
  - eth0 is connected to a PLC which has 192.168.0.99. can ping OK
- 1 virtual connection (vpn_se).
  VPN client attached to 10.0.1.1 (vpn server at amazon). Can ping OK

Current IP addresses on raspberry
wlan0 10.0.0.41
eth0 192.168.0.1
vpn_se 10.0.1.2

**From my amazon server, i require to reach 192.168.0.99.**

i already configured a static route on amazon server

```
route add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.1
```

But im unsure on what to setup on the iptables.

Can you please give me some ideas?

Here is a rough diagram of my current setup
[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTSgf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that Routing is turned on Raspberry PI.

Enable IP Forwarding;

sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf

Add following line

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Then run

sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"

The iptables to allow traffic would be something like

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i vpn_se -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o vpn_se -j ACCEPT

References: https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/